# Web-based remote access of my Carrier Infinity thermostat and Flash end-of-life

Tags: hvac, thermostat, internet, remote-control

I have a Carrier Infinity system, installed some 3 years ago. I was able to access the thermostat over the internet until very recently, because the web access feature uses the Adobe Flash Player which Adobe has now end-of-life'd. I've been aware that Flash was being end-of-life'd for a long time, looking forward to Carrier moving away from it to keep the web access feature alive. I haven't seen any indication of Carrier actually updating the web access feature, although they did recently refresh their website. I can still see the system status via the refreshed site (it never relied on Flash), but can no longer remotely control it because Flash will no longer work.

Has Carrier plotted a path out of this? Do I have to buy a new thermostat to get the remote feature back? Do I have to switch brands, and if so, what about integration with the rest of the "Infinity" system?

Comment: Bloody good question! Have you tried contacting Carrier tech support about it?

Comment: run a stand-alone /portable old copy of a browser to access it.